# Does Proxima Nova font support sixteenths fractions?

Tags: fonts, typesetting, unicode

Our software prints labels using the Proxima Nova font<sup>1</sup>. The software reads data from a CSV file, and if there's a fraction within a field, we replace that fraction with Unicode values. For example,

```
1/2 -> \u00BD
1/3 -> \u2153
1/4 -> \u00BC
```

These are standard Unicode values for common fractions, like 1/2, 1/3, and 1/4. It produces ½, ⅓, and ¼ respectively.

Unfortunately, there don't seem to be standard Unicode values for sixteenths, like 1/16, 3/16, etc. Is there a way to produce sixteenth fractions nicely in the Proxima Nova font? Are there Unicode values that I'm not aware of for sixteenths? Or is there another way?

We have already tried producing sixteenths by creating a superscript character (like superscript 1, 3, etc.) followed by a forward slash and then subscript 16. It looks okay but it still looks noticeably different from other fractions. We are looking for a better solution, if there is one.

---

<sup>1</sup> We are more specifically using Proxima Nova A — Regular as our font, in case it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Proxima Nova](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/s-thin/glyphs.html) seems to have a limited fractions set, however you can build your own by just typing 1/16 or just any fraction, then tick 'Character → OpenType → Fractions', however this may or may not work with your version of InDesign and/or Proxima Nova. Alternatives shown in these videos:

- https://youtu.be/Yx9hFEtJqAQ
- https://youtu.be/U3Sf1RLC7X8

Comment: Where do you tick Character -> Type -> Fractions? In Microsoft Word? We are generating fractions programmatically, from data in a CSV file, so we strictly need the Unicode values, or sequences of Unicode values, to generate fraction glyphs. Would you happen to know what Unicode values or sequences are used when you tick Character -> Type -> Fractions to generate 1/16?

Comment: I should clarify that I don't have InDesign. And we need to do this programmatically, in JavaScript to be specific. We are simply substituting text like 1/2 with the Unicode equivalent of the fraction glyph, and would like to do the same for sixteenths.

Comment: Oh, actually you should have mentioned the tools you are using. I assumed InDesign since this is a graphic design forum and Javascript has little to do with graphic design itself, which makes this more of a programming question. But yes ultimately my answer assumes the use of InDesign, which can "simulate" these characters, otherwise you may be limited to what the font includes in its default character set.

Comment: Is there a website where I can look up all that Proxima Nova A - Regular includes in its character set? Especially, the Unicode values for each glyph?

Comment: I've been searching Google for that but I've been unable to find a resource like this...

Comment: I assume you DO have access to the actual A REGULAR font file, in which case you can use a character map viewer to see the glyphs and assigned unicodes. Again InDesign has its own glyph viewer which can list all the characters and unicodes in a specific font. https://www.fonts.com/font/mark-simonson-studio/proxima-nova/regular click character map

Comment: That URL is very helpful! Thank you! I do have the A REGULAR font file. What should I do with it? Opening it in a text editor doesn't make any sense. Is there some website I can upload it to that will give me a character map based on the font file? Where do I download a free character map viewer to read the font file?

Comment: Depends: PC or Mac? Just google and you should be able to find a free character map viewer for your system. Research a bit. Windows has this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38bTwllsnDw - i don't know about Mac's.

Comment: I use Mac OS X. I found this website, http://mathew-kurian.github.io/CharacterMap/, and uploaded my fonts file. I didn't find sixteenths fractions listed, or even eighths for that matter (although we are still able to display eighths). It actually shows a lot less glyphs than the website you linked me to, i.e. https://www.fonts.com/font/mark-simonson-studio/proxima-nova/regular.

Comment: You may have a different version of the font file. Different vendors can sell slightly different font files. And free versions will have advanced glyphs removed. Research some more ! :)